# O que é e para que serve o php.ini?

Tags: php, configuração, ini

Pode ser até uma pergunta simples mas gostaria de saber o que é o `php.ini` e a sua serventia para um site/sistema.

Se possível, gostaria de boas referências (nem sempre as encontro) que possam ajudar na explicação também.

Comment: php.ini é um arquivo de configuração do PHP no servidor apache, nele são definidas diretivas de funcionamento do interpretador php.

Comment: é independente do apache, Diego..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ele é um arquivo de configurações. Ele possui diretivas de como o PHP deve ser comportar quanto a uso de memória, caminhos, módulos instalados e suas próprias configurações, quais partes do PHP podem ser usados e como serão, limites de uso diversos, etc. Ele possui um [formato padrão chamado de INI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms717987(v=vs.85)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Em geral ele possui configurações que funcionam bem para todos os sites, mas é possível ter várias versões dele e para cada site carregar um com as configurações mais adequadas. Claro que é preciso ter controle da hospedagem para realizar isto. Algumas poucas compartilhadas permitem escolher isso em painel de controle.

A maioria dessas diretivas podem ser mudadas em tempo de execução. Se o uma configuração presente no `php.ini` deixar :P.

As referências primordiais estão no manual oficial.

- http://php.net/manual/en/ini.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

[Mais informações sobre o arquivo INI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

PHP.ini é o arquivo onde estão as configurações do PHP que vão desde extensões, diretivas, configuração de diretórios como o de log, locale padrão.

Serve para definir configurações especificas de um sistema ou de um ambiente(homologação e produção), basicamente esse arquivo define quais 'regras' o PHP deve obedecer por padrão. Algumas configurações podem ser redefinidas em tempo de execução com a função `ini_set('diretiva', 'valor')`.

Ex: Redifir a exibição de erros:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```